# OLE DB Sybase Connection Failing

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sybase

I have a connection to a Sybase database which we stage in a SQL Server 2008R2 database. I can connect the the database and the connection tests out fine. I am using an OLE DB source with a Sybase Driver.

[image: Connection Manager]

I can even preview data. Note I have shrunk this data set so the data can not be seen but it still demonstrates that the source does return rows.

[image: Preview Data Set]

However when I execute the package it results in failure.

[image: Failure]

[source [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fP8M.png)] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "MyDataSource" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

**UPDATE**
Adding other error message in spite of them being the opposite of useful. 
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: component "source" (1) failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: One or more component failed validation.
Error: There were errors during task validation.

**UPDATE**
After a few attempts the account sybase account gets locked. Must have something to do with the password.

Comment: 32 vs 64 bit an issue?

Comment: We are running the package in 32.

Comment: Never dealt with sybase proper - User and password required? Have you consumed data from sybase before or first time? Any other errors or warnings before/after this that may be relevant?

Comment: User and Password is required but set by a project variable. We consume a lot of data from sybase typically through an ODBC connection. I will ad the other errors although they offer little help.

Comment: @Zane how can you say they are not helpful??, I mean `There were errors during task validation`, what else do you want?, that it points you to the error?

Comment: @Lamak that, or at least print the real error message :).

Comment: Have you looked at the Run64BitRuntime debugging option? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/534651/HowplustoplussolveplusSSISpluserrorpluscodeplus-xC

Comment: What value for Delay Validation does your package have? (Try changing it)

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/runeetv/archive/2009/12/22/ssis-package-using-sql-authentication-and-dontsavesensitive-as-protectionlevel.aspx

Comment: You may want to test other connection types odbc, ado etc. just to verify that the package isn't having some authentication issues.

Answer (score 1):

Under **Solution Explorer On Righ Side In BIDS**
---->**RightClick**
     ---->**Properties**
          ---->**Configuration Properties**
               ---->**Debugging**
                    ---->**Debug Options** 
                         ---->**Run64BitRuntime**
                              ---->**False**